# Need some help handling the response I'm getting from json server

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-effect, use-context, json-server

I'm developing an app in React Native in which I'm trying to display some data provided by a fake API I set up using json server. I'm using the useContext hook to handle the general state of the app and since I'm fairly new to React Native and React in general I need some help handling the response I'm manipulating through the context API.

This is the State file I set up in the context folder

```js
import React, { useReducer } from 'react'
import MenusReducer from './MenusReducer'
import MenusContext from './MenusContext'
import { baseUrl } from '../../shared/baseURL'

const MenusState = (props) => {
    const initialState = {
        menus: [],
        selectedMenu: null
    }

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(MenusReducer, initialState)

    const getMenus = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(baseUrl + 'RESTAURANTES')
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log('This is the reducer working'); // This is a test log to see if it works
        dispatch({
            type: 'GET_MENUS',
            payload: data
        })
    }

    const getDetails = async (id) => {
        const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}RESTAURANTES/${id}`)
        const data = await response.json()
        dispatch({
            type: 'GET_DETAILS',
            payload: data
        })
    }

    return (
        <MenusContext.Provider value={{
            menus: state.menus,
            selectedMenu: state.selectedMenu,
            getMenus,
            getDetails
        }}>
            {props.children}
        </MenusContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default MenusState;
```

So here I set up a getMenus() function by which I get all the items I'd like to display in my components. As you can see, I put a test log inside the function to see if it works, which it does.

The problem comes when I try to get those items inside my app components. Here's one of the instances in which I try to get the items to display.

```js
const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { menus, getMenus } = useContext(MenusContext)
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
    const [response, setResponse] = useState([])
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState(allCategories)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        const data = async () => await getMenus();
        console.log('This is the app executing');
        setLoading(false);
        setResponse(data)
        console.log(response);
    }, [])
    
    // ... some code later
    
    return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.yScroll}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Destacados</Text>
                </View>
                <ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
                    <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                        <Text>{response[0]}</Text> // Here's where I'm trying to print something about the response but it's not working
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Categorias</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                    {categories.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <View  key={index} style={styles.category}>
                                <Text>{item}</Text>
                            </View>
                        )
                    })}
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
    )
}
```

So inside one of the ScrollViews I'm setting up a test to see if the response can be displayed, which it is not. However, inside the useEffect, I'm setting up a test log with the message 'This is the app executing' which is working, BUT, the response being logged is an empty array.

I'm sure  the problem I'm facing has something to do with the asynchronous response between app and server, but I have no clear idea as to how I can address this.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, I think you can do this

```
const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
const { menus, getMenus } = useContext(MenusContext)
const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
const [categories, setCategories] = useState(allCategories)
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {
    const data = async () => await getMenus();
    console.log('This is the app executing');
    data();
    setLoading(false);
    
}, [])

// ... some code later

return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.yScroll}>
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Destacados</Text>
            </View>
            <ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
                <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                    <Text>{menus[0]}</Text> // Here's where I'm trying to print something about the response but it's not working
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Categorias</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                {categories.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <View  key={index} style={styles.category}>
                            <Text>{item}</Text>
                        </View>
                    )
                })}
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
)
```

}